# Use HMM for time series classification in python - define initial states

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification, python, hidden-markov-model

I have a time series of locations. I want to use HMM for classification of path, by using the knowledge I have on the locations.
I know that locations [0,100] should be state A , [100,200] are state B , and so on for 6 states.
The assumption is that I should have 4 classes of time series in my data, such that each class should present different probabilities. For example, for the class "Mild", it is very likely to move from state A to B. But , for class "Severe", it should differ.
I don't know the initial probabilities but I know the exact mapping of location to state and that they should defer.
Each sample is 1-D time series of locations.
How can I do this (model the states, find probabilities) in python and use it for classification?
I couldn't find any similar tutorial or example.

Comment: Are the states always at the same location? If so then you don't have hidden states, and can probably do much better than HMM. For example transform your input from a general 2D location into distance to each of the states. Or even drop all stars but the closest one, and track state,distance for that one. This might even be reducible to just the closest state sequence, or inject tokens to represent in between states when distance is high.

Comment: @jonnor The locations are all 1D and I always have 5 states : before ROI1 , ROI1 , between ROIs , ROI2 , after ROI2. I basically want to classify samples to label based on pattern of transitions between them. I have 32 possible routes - all of them has these 5 states , but the exact location of each differs between the 32. All location belongs to one of these 5 states , for each sample and for each routes. What do you think will be the best approach?